# Bilingual Navigation

Tags: usability, navigation, accessibility

I am working on a pro-bono project. We are designing a website for a bilingual parent workshop (80% Spanish Speakers and 20% English Speakers). Funders for the organization are English speakers. That is why we must include both languages. We have limited resources with development. Design is being asked to creative with the tasks.

I was asked to include both languages on the navigation (Spanish and English).

The navigation would look something like this:
Home/Inicio About/Sobre Nosotros Gallery/Galleria

Are there any UX rules that goes against what I am being asked to do? I've never seen a navigation like this before.

[image]

Comment: Have the funders asked explicitly that both languages appear at the same time? Or just that it is possible to navigate the site in both languages?

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure it's clear which language is which by having some delimiter between the two languages.  The text of your question said "Home/Inicio" but the screen shot just looked like "Home Inicio" (stacked vertically) so it might not be clear.  A slash or dash or parens is needed.  Parentheses might *not* be wanted because that might imply a "secondary" language and you don't want people to feel "secondary".

Also, and this is more of an implementation detail, make sure the default language of the page is set (`<html lang="es">` or `<html lang="en">`) **and** make sure the *other* language (whichever one is not the default language) uses the `lang` property anytime that language used.

For example:

```
<html lang="es">
<!-- stuff on page -->
<a href="home">
  <span lang="en">home</span> 
  <span aria-hidden="true">/</span>
  inicio
</a>
```

or

```
<html lang="en">
<!-- stuff on page -->
<a href="home">
  home
  <span aria-hidden="true">/</span>
  <span lang="es">inicio</span>
</a>
```